# Datatables OR search?

Tags: javascript, search, datatables

I'm using the [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin.

I want to search the table if a term shown in at least one of two specific columns.

The current code below only finds rows where the word `"word"` is in **both** columns. I need to find rows where the word is in **either** of the columns.

```
$table.DataTable().columns([0,1]).search("word");
```

I've considered using global search and setting searchable option of other columns to false, but I couldn't find a way to change this option at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Search all columns

You can use regular expressions when searching a table.

For example, the code below shows search results containing either word `Angelica` or `London` in all columns.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table
    .search('Angelica|London', true, false)
    .draw();
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35od8zz7/) for code and demonstration.

#### Search specific columns

To search specific columns you may need to utilize [custom search](http://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search) functionality.

The code below shows search results containing either word `Angelica` or `Tokyo` in table data values with indexes `0`, `1`, and `2`.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var terms = ['Angelica', 'Tokyo'];    

// Convert terms to lower case
$.each(terms, function(index, value){
   terms[index] = value.toLowerCase();
});

// Enable custom search
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var isFound = false;
      $.each(data, function (index, value){         
         // Evaluate only first three data values
         if(index === 0 || index === 1 || index === 2){
            // Convert data to lower case
            value = value.toLowerCase();
            $.each(terms, function(termIndex, termValue){
               // If data contains the term
               if (value.indexOf(termValue) !== -1) {
                  isFound = true;
               }
               return !isFound;
            });
         }

         return !isFound;
      });

      return isFound;
   }
);

// Perform search
table.draw();

// Disable custom search
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35od8zz7/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: It's not his question, he want to use only 2 columns in the DataTable

Comment: @JeanDoux, good point. Added alternative (more complex) solution if OP wants to search specific columns.

Comment: The custom search looks like what I need, though I need to search ONE (not two) term that is found in either of specific two columns. So I guess I dont need the $.each part in the code?   Second, how do I enable/disable the custom search at runtime? Means I don't want the plugin to always apply this custom search, I want to disable/enable it in code.

Comment: @user3599803, custom search is disabled with `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();`, see the posted code.

Comment: Ok, so each time after I use custom search, I pop this function from the array? Since I don't want to lose the normal global search. So I think I should just store the custom search function in a variable, then push/pop the function when I need. Thanks

Comment: @user3599803, that should work too. You're correct, use `push()`/`pop()` to enable/disable custom search.